# Why do I need IP addresses in bitcoins, isn't I working with public address?

Tags: client, protocol, address

Sorry for that question, but please I would like to understand why should I have IP addresses as I can only communicate using the public address

Sorry again but really I am confused

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do, what you think you need for this, and why do you think so?

Comment: Your question is word salad and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what I mean, how can the network know the person needed for communication, for example Bob wants to send money to Alice so bob includes Alice Public address
my question why do I need an IP address for that?
Sorry again

Comment: Where do you read that you need an IP address?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a new Bitcoin transaction, all you will need is the receiver's public Bitcoin address (and your bitcoin wallet).

The transaction must eventually be broadcast to the network, though this can be done in a variety of ways. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Network for more details.